# What is the way to drop RDS database that is being used in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While it's easy to simple delete the database and create new one. I don't want to do that because as far as I know you can't not add new database to Elastic Beanstalk.

And between IAM roles, Security groups, VPC subnets, opening ports, passing env variables, load balancing and more... I don't want to go through trouble of deleting integrated db and then doing surgery to integrate new one to EBS.

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalk will run your software, and that you run RDS or not.. is optional.
RDS is a different thing. You can drop RDS databases that are inside a RDS instance.